# BIOS Legacy and GPT partitioned external HDD installed with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Boot repair result shows error about sectors

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bios, boot-repair, gpt

Why does the error show during boot-repair? FYI: My external HDD size 4TiB.

> ERROR: unsupported sector size 4096 on

I have my machine which shows as:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lscpu
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          2
On-line CPU(s) list:             0,1
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              2
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           42
Model name:                      Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU B950 @ 2.10GHz
Stepping:                        7
CPU MHz:                         892.831
CPU max MHz:                     2100.0000
CPU min MHz:                     800.0000
BogoMIPS:                        4190.35
L1d cache:                       64 KiB
L1i cache:                       64 KiB
L2 cache:                        512 KiB
L3 cache:                        2 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0,1
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     KVM: Vulnerable
Vulnerability L1tf:              Mitigation; PTE Inversion
Vulnerability Mds:               Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT disabled
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Mitigation; PTI
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled v
                                 ia prctl and seccomp
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user
                                  pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Full generic retpoline, IBPB condit
                                 ional, IBRS_FW, STIBP disabled, RSB filling
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtr
                                 r pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx f
                                 xsr sse sse2 ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm con
                                 stant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl x
                                 topology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmu
                                 lqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 x
                                 tpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_d
                                 eadline_timer xsave lahf_lm epb pti ssbd ibrs i
                                 bpb stibp xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts md_clear
                                  flush_l1d
```

IT's NOT EFI instead BIOS Bootable:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ efibootmgr
EFI variables are not supported on this system.
```

I have followed [this](https://fitzcarraldoblog.wordpress.com/2017/02/10/partitioning-hard-disk-drives-for-bios-mbr-bios-gpt-and-uefi-gpt-in-linux/) article about BIOS-GPT Linux partioning process. The blogger confirms about possibilities of such installation in GPT Partitioned disk using BIOS based machine.

I have tried BIOS-GPT (option 1 and 3). None of those options worked to boot linux alongside with another OS (Win7) installed before in internal HDD.

The boot-repair tools gives the following result:

Both options shows:

```
=============================== StdErr Messages ================================

ERROR: unsupported sector size 4096 on /dev/sdc.
ERROR: unsupported sector size 4096 on /dev/sdc.
```

Pastebin URLs: [Option 1](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QXT4SjGMmJ/)

Comment: Have you used gdisk or gparted to partition external drive? The partitions then are logically 512 even though drive is 4K. You also have Windows fast start up on, that needs to be off.

Comment: Yes I did partitions using gparted. But how did you know mine is fast start up on? if so how to turn it off ?

Comment: Boot-Repair says partition(s) are in unsafe state/hibernation. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I will try again and feedback here.

Comment: From this  (https://fitzcarraldoblog.wordpress.com/2017/02/10/partitioning-hard-disk-drives-for-bios-mbr-bios-gpt-and-uefi-gpt-in-linux/) link find BIOS+GPT partition "Option 1" where I have used a separate partition for boot to external HDD. THe hibernate issue did not show up there. But the error keeps showing up at the end of log "ERROR: unsupported sector size 4096 on /dev/sdd." - if you are familiar with this let me know. If disabling "Fast boot" solves problem for "Option 3" I will acknowledge here.

Comment: @oldfred if I run "powercfg -h OFF" that should stop "unsafe state/hibernation" right?

Comment: I have used separate partition for /boot and stopped fastboot using "powercfg -h OFF" before linux installation. the paste bin is (https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QXT4SjGMmJ/)

Comment: If error is just on your flash drive installer, then it is normal. Flash drive does not have standard configuration. Since installs are BIOS, best to always boot live installer or any Windows repair disk in BIOS mode, not UEFI mode. Shows live installer with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI  But if system is UEFI, you may want to plan on eventually converting to UEFI/gpt. Requires good backups as change from MBR to gpt will normally erase drive.